# Node/Express server controller calling async local function returning too soon

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I have an API endpoint created using Node/Express. I want to call a local function from the controller function asynchronously, but the called local function is immediately returning `undefined` rather than the asynchronous results:

```
module.exports = {
    sendMail: (req, res) => {
        (async () => {
            await testAsync("email","token").then(function(result){ 
                console.log(result); //logs undefined
                res.json("result=" + result);
            });
        })();
    },
};


async function testAsync(email, token){
    await setTimeout(function(){
            return email;
        }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: please dont use `await` in combination with `.then()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first remove the async IIFE you dont really need it. Then remove the `.then()` and go with a `try / catch`. Please dont use `.then()` with `async / await` you either go with `.then()` chaining or `async / await` but not both:
`

```
module.exports = {
    sendMail: async (req, res) => {
            try {
               let result = await testAsync("email","token");
               res.json("result=" + result);

            }catch(err){
               res.json(err);
            }


    },
};
```

Also `await` works on promises, so you need to return an promise here. You also dont need `async` here:

```
function testAsync(email, token){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
       setTimeout(function(){
            resolve("works");
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `setTimeout()` in a Promise.
Like this:

```
async function testAsync(email, token) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(email);
        }, 1000)
    });
}
```